# Should I receive the self-learner badge for this question?

Tags: support, badges

I asked [How to disable in the node debugger "break on first line"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16420374/how-to-disable-in-the-node-debugger-break-on-first-line).

After a few days of research, I found out the answer. The question had already 3 votes and I answered the question. Shouldn't this generate a "Self-Learner" badge?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The **answer** must receive a score of 3, not the question.

Your answer currently has a score of 1, so you'll have to wait and see if it'll receive enough upvotes. If it hits a score of 3, you'll be eligible for the self-learner badge.

From [List of all badges with full descriptions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions):

> #### Self-Learner
>
> - bronze; awarded once
> - Provide **an answer** to your own question **that receives a score of three**

Emphasis mine.

Comment: The badge description says something about a "question with score of 3 or more"

Comment: @Gabriel: You have to read the sentence correctly (which is quite common with badges): *"(Answered) [your own question] (with score of 3 or more)"* - "Answered" actually goes to "with score of 3 or more"

Comment: @GabrielPetrovay: No, it says '*an answer* to your own question with a score of 3 or more.'

Comment: Thanks @Martin! This list helps!

Comment: Perhaps the badge text should be made clearer? *"Provide an answer with a score of 3 or more to your own question"*

Comment: @jmac: that would certainly be an improvement.

Comment: This is going to be another one of those "need to start another meta question for the request" things, isn't it...

Comment: @jmac: sounds like you have an excellent `feature-request` question right there. :-)

Comment: @jmac: I'd vote that up. :P

Comment: @jmac I fixed the community wiki list, but the official list of badges will depend on that feature request :)

Comment: And it has been added as a feature request [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/181111/editing-the-self-learner-badge-description) so please go ahead and show your support there! @bfavaretto

Comment: @GabrielPetrovay: And congratulations, I see you now earned the badge. :-)

Comment: @MartijnPieters Thanks! I was just wondering Martijn, what have you done in the past 4 years besides answering questions. How can you do it? (Rethorical)

Comment: @GabrielPetrovay: *Most* of those 4 years [I didn't do much](http://stackexchange.com/users/35417/martijn-pieters?tab=reputation), actually..