# Editing the "Self-Learner" Badge Description

Tags: feature-request, badges, badge-description

Stemming from [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/181100/should-i-receive-the-self-learner-badge-for-this-question/181101?noredirect=1#comment550191_181101) the text for "Self-Learner" badge is pretty easy to get confused by.

#### Current Text

> Answered your own question with score of 3 or more

#### Issue

The person in the above question was confused as they thought they needed to answer their own question, and that the question had to have a score of 3 or more. What it actually means is that they have to answer their own question, and the **answer** needs to have a score of three or more. The way it is phrased is ambiguous, so why not make it clear?

#### Suggestion

Edit the text as follows:

> Provide an answer with a score of 3 or more to your own question

No more confusion.

Comment: So why isn't this implemented yet?

Answer (score 4):

I'd agree but I would use:

> Answer your own question achieving a score of 3 or more.

It sounds more in keeping with the rest of the descriptions and the word achieving is more positive (probably not the right word but it kinda works).